# Showing data from certain user (android studio java programming + firebase)

Tags: java, android

I'm having a trouble on retrieving data from firebase. My current project is about mobile banking and is working on checking user balance.

At first, I add a value which is `$1000` and saved to the database

After that, I don't know how to take those `$1000` to show to the user when they're using `Check Account Balance` feature.

I'm currently stuck here and struggling.

Comment: Please share some code with us so that this community can help you.

Comment: The code is too long to put it in the comment, so I share it via docs :)

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TFmyFp8iA_kr2GDAzxscEWi1mnkteN8U5oztnmWOWjA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your firebase DB structure, but I think you can follow the below-given link to retrieve the data from the firebase

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

For Example, You can use the below code to get a callback to be called once and then immediately removed

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("/balance");

    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // ...
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // ...
      }
    });
```

Firebase also provides the other way to retrieve the data also for that you can follow the above link.

Comment: Hi, relating to the code, do you mind to explain it to me what "server/saving-data/fireblog/posts" cames from?

Comment: @arvinkosasih It is just for example. For your case, lets say your node name is **balance** then you can get the reference of that node like this **FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/balance")**

Comment: Hi, I did exactly the same code as you describe, before the program crashed everytime I ran it, but now it works without crashing.
But what happen next is the program cannot retrieve value from the database